# Text shaking when using css transition and scale()

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have searched everywhere, including SO, but no one seems to find an answer. My issue is that when I hover an element using `transform: scale(1.2)` and `opacity`, the element grows, which is fine, but the text/content shakes or wiggles as it appears and scales.

Is there a way to stop the text from shaking/wiggling/flickering, as it's annoying and not UX friendly?

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dv78etsv/

Many Thanks

Comment: Transitions are powerful, but they have their limits.  The jerkiness disappears if you exclude the rules to change the text size or if you only transition opacity (`transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;` on line 40ish or remove the `font-size` rules on line 105ish).  Not really an answer, but I would just tone down some of those transitions to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run a couple transitions at the same time, simply remove all the transitions and decide on one - for specific css property `transition: opacity 1s`

remove changing font-size on hover, and don't over-use transitions, those two should be enough:

```
.carte-sample {
    transition: transform 1s;
}
.carte-inner {
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

working example
http://jsfiddle.net/dv78etsv/2/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, i tried:

`box-sizing: border-box;`

and it seemed to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).